# /home/vsts/work/_temp/50f809a3-dad0-487b-9185-3b6f479e490a.sh: line 9: databricks: command not found

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am running a yaml pipeline with below part of code:

```yaml
- script: |
      pip install databricks-cli
      export DATABRICKS_HOST=https://$(databricks-workspace-url)
      export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=$(databricks-workspace-token)

      databricks workspace rm --recursive /folder
```

When this part of code is on direct yml pipeline, this works fine.

But when I move this part to a template yml file, this fails with below error:

> /home/vsts/work/_temp/XYZ.sh: line 9: databricks: command not found
> ##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.

Any tip, clue or solution ?